# ID affecting processing on input elements

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I'm trying to sort out validation issues on a selection of forms. The main error that is cropping up is duplicate IDs on input elements like buttons.

This is the message:

> Error: Duplicate ID my id.
>
> From line 258, column 25; to line 258, column 96

This is an example of a button.

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit"/>
```

I know that the ID can sometime be used with JavaScript processing but does the ID affect the way the form handles the element in anyway? I've also got IDs on hidden input elements.

```
<input type="hidden" name="value" id="value" value="5"/>
```

Surly I shouldn't need to talk to them even with JavaScript and there's nothing to style if they are hidden?
If we assume I'm not using script and just posting a standard form, would the IDs have any effect on it and so it would be safe to change them to make them unique or remove them?

Comment: Where is the error coming from (console/validator?) and could you include the exact error message? This will make it easier to assess the issue.

Comment: Okay. Edited question,

Comment: id's need to be unique, you can use a class for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The anserw is no - id attribute does not affect an form.

Your error is quite obvious. Somewhere in HTML structure, You defined two (or more) elements with same ID.
Since I don't know what is in line 258 of Your file, I cannot help more than that.

Comment: I knew I had two duplicate IDs but if they don't effect the form then it should be safe to change them to make then unique or remove them. Is that right?

Comment: Yep. Your form element doesn't care about ID's of elements inside it. All ID's have to be unique, and thats basically everything You need to know ;)

Comment: Can you think of any occasion where a hidden input would need an ID. You wouldn't be styling it and I can think of any reason to need to talk to it with a script?

Comment: Well I would go for id attribute just in case if I would have to search for this element very often (because document.getElementById is the fastest selector) and reach to it with JS for some reason.

In other case, You should just rely on css classes. Setting ID for elements just to style them is not recommended.

Comment: There are use cases for selecting hidden inputs with Javascript. For example, you could create a unique identifier for the user when the form is rendered and set this to the hidden inputs `value` property. Then when the user submits their data, your autogenerated ID is included with their data.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, the id has no effect on how the parent form element handles inputs, this is done through the `name` property which is passed to `POST` or `GET`.
If you are not including any Javascript libraries or  referencing ID's in scripts of your own then you should be fine to change the ID's to uniquify them.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem for your form, and browsers have never made it into a problem either.

Your IDE / editor is however right to complain about it, as it's not how they're supposed to be used.

But can it cause any harm? Normally not. Selecting the wrong element at worst.

QuerySelectorAll and CSS don't even care, but jQuery does:

[image: Different tools respond differently to duplicate IDs]

Comment: Well it's not about chrome, it's about querySelectorAll

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp

' returns all elements in the document that matches a specified CSS selector(s)'

So there's nothing wrong with that, that's how it is specified.

Comment: I know that I wouldn't cause a problem but it goes against W3C standards and although the page works, at least if you page validates it looks professional and also means that your code is telling the browser extactly what to do rather than leave the browser to guess.

Comment: @grzesiekgs - I'll make a subtle adjustment to my post, thanks for letting me know.